# Fabricjs: Export canvas by toUrlData from custom position

Tags: canvas, position, export, fabricjs

I have a problem with toUrlData.

I use tool-pan to pan my canvas to a random position then export it by toURLData(). It 's alway export my canvas from the root(0,0).

I want to export the canvas that I have panned to.

> **Example: I pan to A(-200,-200), now I want to export png from A with custom width and height. But It 's alway export my canvas from the root(0,0).**

How to export by toUrlData from custom position ?

Comment: Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/NfZVb/514/)

Comment: Thank you, but it's not my case